# One Way WCF Contract, MSMQ and Throwing Exceptions

Tags: wcf, exception, message-queue, msmq

I created a WCF service contract that works against MSMQ. Since it is MSMQ, I use one-way communication:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
```

In my service implementation, I have `OperationBehavior` to automatically commit transactions:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionAutoComplete = true, TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
```

This makes sure WCF handles any exceptions by putting the message on a retry queue (per my configuration). It seems odd to be throwing an exception from a one-way operation. Is this the correct way to tell WCF not to commit the transaction?

Comment: the question is bit vague? you mean, you are getting exception in the client calling the service, or are you simply seeing an exception in this service method?

Comment: i think your problem may be TransactionScopeRequired. check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionscoperequired(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am only asking whether throwing exceptions is the correct way to rollback the transaction in WCF when working with MSMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that throwing an exception is the *only* way to tell WCF to use the built-in retry sub-queue. This exception is swallowed by WCF. It is also used to make sure the transaction isn't auto-completed.

Comment: I was able to get the transaction to go to the retry subqueue by starting processing with: Transaction qTransaction = Transaction.Current; and ending with: qTransaction.Rollback(); when I want to rollback.  Not calling Rollback and allowing the OperationContract to run to the end of processing will commit the transaction and remove it from the main queue.